# MR- Iterator over Iteration, Can't parse value for output

Tags: mapreduce, iterator

The raw file for mapreduce is like this (delimiter: Tab)

> `Apple   11  12  13`
>
> `Orange   15  26  10`

When I try to implement the method to add a new feature and separate the numbers using ",", my expected output should be like this:

> `Apple    3.0:11,12,13`
>
> `Orange   3.0:15,26,10`

But the final output gets like below:

> `Apple    3.0:11  12  13`
>
> `Orange   3.0:15  26  10`

I try to print the result for tracing, but it seems next() will skip the parsing and directly jump out the loop. Can anyone help on this?

```
public static class Mapper1 extends MapReduceBase 
    implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    @Override
  public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
    Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        output.collect(key, value); 
    }       
}

public static class Reducer1 extends MapReduceBase 
    implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        String feature = "3.0:"; 
        boolean first = true;
        while(values.hasNext()) {
            if(!first) {
                feature += ",";
            }           
            feature += values.next().toString() ;
    System.out.println("count"+feature.length+","+feature);  
            first = false;
        }
        output.collect(key, new Text(feature));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your mapper only emits one key value pair for each record, which is not expected. You can check your mapper's output by setting the reducer number to 0 in your driver code:

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

Mapper input:

> Apple   11  12  13
>
> Orange   15  26  10

Actual mapper output: (key, value)

> (Apple, 11 12 13)
>
> (Orange, 15 26 10)

Expected mapper output: (key, value)

> (Apple, 11)
>
> (Apple, 12)
>
> ...
>
> (Orange, 10)

You can either modify your mapper to emit multiple key value pairs for each record, or use split() method of String class to get the substrings from the original one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I'm think of using split() to emit multiple key value pairs for each record, but then I checked the original input file and found there exists a single key `Strawberry` without any value behind, in this case, the (key,value) may not be generated successfully, any guidance on this?

Comment: Normally, if you have a broken record in your data file, simply ignore that record. In your program, you can check the length of your `value` in mapper, and only emit key value pairs with postive length. You may be also interested in a mapreduce feature called `counter` to record the bad ones.